# 'No matching constructor for initialization' when returning a C++ object

Tags: c++, constructor, llvm

I have a simple object, and I want to return an object in a method. I know the constructor used is valid since it's used somewhere else.

```
return Color(red, blue, green);
```

This codes returns the following error : `No matching constructor for initialization of 'transitLib::Color'`

However, just adding `*new` make the thing work :

```
return *new Color(red, blue, green); //Valid, apparently.
```

Any idea why this would produce this error?

Attached is the full code of the class

.h

```
class Color {

    float red;
    float blue;
    float green;

public:
    Color(float red, float blue, float green);
    Color(Color &color);

    Color colorByInterpolating(Color const& destinationColor, float fraction);

    bool operator==(const Color &other) const;
    bool operator!=(const Color &other) const;
    Color operator=(const Color &other);

    float getRed();
    float getBlue();
    float getGreen();
};
```

.cpp

```
transitLib::Color::Color(float red, float blue, float green):red(red),blue(blue),green(green){}
transitLib::Color::Color(Color &color):red(color.red),blue(color.blue),green(color.green){}

Color transitLib::Color::colorByInterpolating(Color const& destinationColor, float fraction) {
    return Color(red + fraction * (destinationColor.red - red), blue + fraction * (destinationColor.blue - blue), green + fraction * (destinationColor.green - green));
}

bool Color::operator==(const Color &other) const {
    return other.red == red && other.blue == blue && other.green == green;
}

bool Color::operator!=(const Color &other) const {
    return !(other == *this);
}

Color Color::operator=(const Color &other) {
    red = other.red;
    blue = other.blue;
    green = other.green;

    return *this;
}

float transitLib::Color::getRed() {
    return red;
}

float transitLib::Color::getBlue() {
    return blue;
}

float transitLib::Color::getGreen() {
    return green;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you return by value, a copy is being made (using the copy constructor). You're attempting to return a **temporary**, which can't bind to a non-const reference (which is your copy constructor takes as a parameter).

Change

```
Color(Color &color);
```

to

```
Color(const Color &color);
```

Comment: This was indeed it, I knew it was a simple answer. Thanks.

Comment: @gcamp also note that `operator =` should return `*this` by reference (that's the idiomatic way)

Comment: Similar error brought me to this post.  In my case I had the following (reformatted to match this post's code)

explicit Color(const Color &rhs)

I had to remove the explicit directive but don't understand why the explicit keyword was causing me to get same error message